# Hide radiobutton when one value is selected from Dropdownlist using angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a dropdownlist which binds values as `SITE`,`FIBER` & `OTHERS` and below that there are 2 radibuttons named as `Approve` and `Reject`.

Now what I want is I want to hide the `Reject` radio button if `FIBER` is selected from the dropdownlist.

How to achieve this using Angular JS?

Below is my code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- dropdownlist -->

<select class="form-control" id="FiberLead_ddlUtility" ng-model="UtilityModel" ng-change="refreshAllDllCMM()">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option ng-value="UTILITY" ng-repeat="UTILITY in UTILITYS">{{UTILITY}}</option>
</select>

                                            
                                            
                                            
<!-- Radio button -->


<div class="customeRadioWrap">
    <div class="customeRadio">
        <input type="radio" id="rdApprove" name="radio-group"
               ng-value="true" ng-model="radioAppRejSelected">
        <label for="rdApprove">Approve</label>
    </div>
    <div class="customeRadio">
        <input type="radio" id="rdReject" name="radio-group"
               ng-value="false" ng-model="radioAppRejSelected">
        <label for="rdReject">Reject</label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default customBtn"
            ng-click="ConfirmApproveRejectCMM()">
      <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      Submit
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-if directive to achieve that. Code below will hide the reject button when utilitymodels value is FIBER.

```
<div class="customeRadio" ng-if="UtilityModel != 'FIBER'">
    <input type="radio" id="rdReject" name="radio-group" ng-value="false" ng-model="radioAppRejSelected">
    <label for="rdReject">Reject</label>
</div>
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/6vznXpar6oKyOh0KNBZc?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks for the fast response, I tried but it is not working as expected. Also, there is no error in console

Comment: @BN Added plunker demo for you, please compare your code with the working example.

Comment: yes, its working in plunker. but I have no idea why its not working in my application

Comment: you know what when I changed my code `ng-if="UtilityModel == 'FIBER'"` then on load the `Reject` button was hidden.

Comment: i also tried disabling like this `<div class="customeRadio" ng-disabled="(UtilityModel == 'FIBER')">
                                    <input type="radio" id="rdReject" name="radio-group"
                                           ng-value="false" ng-model="radioAppRejSelected">
                                    <label for="rdReject">Reject</label>
                                </div>` but this also didn't worked

Comment: Create a plunker, I would gladly help you debug it.

Comment: finally got it updated.. have a look https://plnkr.co/edit/IXsgRxsGroA1a58NpU6O?p=preview

Comment: @BN it also works in your plunker (plnkr.co/edit/IXsgRxsGroA1a58NpU6O?p=preview)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191633/discussion-between-b-n-and-ntp).

Comment: are u busy ?? can u come again on chat ?

Comment: see this https://plnkr.co/edit/w9wYNQWsqdXP6hVtUDxb?p=preview its not working. same as my application

Comment: upvoted it mate. thanks for your efforts. I will check for the solutions if any and let you know

Comment: you do not have angularjs included in your plunker, please create a working sample. That way I will be able to better help you with this problem.